# iOS - Risks involving Public Beta App distribution

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, beta-testing

Recently I have been working on an app with sensitive user information in `Keychain` and regular information in `UserDefults` (which we also want to be protected as in Appstore build).
Now my team want's to test this app with public beta through testflight and we are concerned if it has same security as of Released app on Appstore.

I have searched a lot but unable to get any security related information for public beta.

> So is there any security threat with public beta distribution of iOS
> app through AppStoreConnect / Testflight?

Will appreciate your involvement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is secure, the only difference I can think of is that Testflight version will collect more data than usual from these users such as logs and screenshots (with user permission and triggered by user)